# Shortcut to accept top spelling suggestion of the last word

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, spelling

Say I'm typing into a document and I make a typo. I've got to the end of the misspelled word and it has a red line of dots under it. I right click and choose the top suggestion (which is nearly always right) and continue writing my document.

It there a way to do this without using the mouse to choose the suggestion?

EDIT:
I don't have auto correct spelling on as it's a massive pain. There are a lot of words that I don't want to have corrected. So I have it turned off. However there are regularly ones that I do want to correct and I want to be able to take a chance at correcting that last misspelled word.

I know that this cannot be done with the default OSX settings.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**
If you want it to be automatically corrected, go to **System preferences > Keyboard > Text** and turn on "Correct spelling automatically".

[image: Keyboard settings pane]

---

*Original answer:*

> Which OS X version are you on?
>
> I'm on Mavericks and if I move the cursor so it touches the misspelled word, the suggestion pops up automatically and I can chose the correct one using the arrow keys.
>
> [image: Screenshot of text suggestion]

Comment: I don't want to have to choose the suggestion. I'd like to have a command that behaved like Google's I'm Feeling Lucky option and just corrected it to the first most likely option.

Comment: Not sure if OS X version older than Mavericks have the setting, but you can turn on `Correct spelling automatically` under Keyboard settings. Edited my original answer.